# How do i change this number into Number Format

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have this code in javascript [ `<strong>${item.party_election_result_obtained_vote} </strong>` ]. How can i change this to a number format

```
<strong>${item.party_election_result_obtained_vote} </strong>
```

i want the code to be in number format, as it stands now, it reads something like 1000, i want it to read 1,000

Comment: A popular answer implies the use of regex [How to print a number with commas as thousands separators in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Intl.NumberFormat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat)

In example :

```js
// us format
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US').format(1000.42));

// french format
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('fr-FR').format(1000.42));
```

Comment: please re-write my code in number format since i'm a newbie. Thank you

Comment: You will never progress if you expect others to code for you.